# Auto-update other sheets

Tags: google-forms

Responses are automatically added to the sheet `Form Responses`. I want to apply certain formulas in a sheet called `Student Answers`. However, `Student Answers` doesn't auto-update from the submitted responses. Here are the formulas I am trying to use:

```
='Form Responses'!A1` etc.
=IF('Form Responses'!E6='Answers'!$E$2,1,0)
```

`Answers` is another sheet with an answer key.

```
=SUM(D5:I5)
```

this sums the numbers given in the previous formula.

Basically, I have created a quiz, and I want to grade the quiz on a separate sheet.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqvTp4ajjRSUdGlQNDV5cUd4TVFmeFB3TndJeTBLblE&usp=sharing) is the Sheets in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `=ARRAYFORMULA`. Here are my working examples:

- `=ArrayFormula('Student Submissions'!A:C)` for basic copying of columns
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(If('Student Submissions'!D3:D='Student Submissions'!D3,1,0))` for `IF` statements
- `=ArrayFormula(mmult(D3:I;TRANSPOSE(sign(column(D3:I)))))` for `SUM`
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(J3:J/6*100)` for `AVERAGE` and percent

Note: I found these answers in the Google Product forums but cannot find the link again.